# Error when executing bigramtagger from nltk module in python

Tags: python, nltk, pos-tagger

I am trying to train the bigramtagger with training set acquired from CMU ARK Twitter Part-of-Speech Tagger v0.3.2 http://www.ark.cs.cmu.edu/TweetNLP/ the training set contains tagged tweets but when i try and train it i get an error:

```
File "/Applications/PyCharm Edu.app/Contents/helpers/pycharm/pycharm_setup_runner.py", line 26, in <module>
    exec (fh.read(), globals(), locals())
  File "<string>", line 41, in <module>
  File "/Users/ravinkohli/Library/Python/3.5/lib/python/site-packages/nltk/tag/sequential.py", line 341, in __init__
    backoff, cutoff, verbose)
  File "/Users/ravinkohli/Library/Python/3.5/lib/python/site-packages/nltk/tag/sequential.py", line 288, in __init__
    self._train(train, cutoff, verbose)
  File "/Users/ravinkohli/Library/Python/3.5/lib/python/site-packages/nltk/tag/sequential.py", line 179, in _train
    tokens, tags = zip(*sentence)
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)
```

my code is

```
from nltk import tag
import nltk

def read_from_file(file):
    f = open(file, "r")
    data = []
    row = []
    for line in f:
        if line != "\n":
            row.append(line)
        elif line == "\n":
            data.append(row)
            row = []

    list_item = []
    data_final = []
    for item in data:
        for row1 in item:
            row1 = row1.replace("\n","")
            row1 = row1.split(" ")
            list_item.append(row1)
        data_final.append(list_item)
        list_item=[]
    return data_final

data = read_from_file("pos_training.txt")

list_item = []
final_tags = []

for row in data:
    for item in row:
        print(item)
        tagged_token = tag.str2tuple(item[0] + "/" + item[1])
        list_item.append(tagged_token)
    final_tags.append(list_item)
    list_item = []

bigram_tagger = nltk.BigramTagger(final_tags)
```

[link to the training set](https://github.com/brendano/ark-tweet-nlp/blob/master/data/ritter/orig/pos.txt)